# Set selected mvc3 combobox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a combo box using MVC3.  I want to set the selected value in the combo box on a click event from a webgrid.  I am setting the value using

```
$("#trainingCenterString").val($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
```

MVC puts spaces in the combo box values and with the spaces the select doesn't work.  When the spaces are removed the select works.  Does jQuery have "like", "trim" something like that that can be used to set this?

Comment: Dude, google "jquery trim": http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  trim strings?

Comment: i found the code to trim a string.  I am trying to set a combo box.  Because there are spaces around the combo box items my set doesn't match and the combo isn't set.  How can I do something like, set combo box where combo box like...?  or in setting something like combobox.trim = ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looking at just triming the spaces you can try this:

```
  var item='hello there again'.replace(/[' ']/g,'');
  alert(item);​
```

**EDIT**

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/XrDY4/5/) that includes a click event to set the selected index that should help you.

Comment: I am sorry for not conveying my question well enough.  Using your fiddler example.  I am trying to set the combobox so that value 2 is the one that is selected.  I am doing this using $("#drop1").val('2');  This works in your example but my issue is the MVC generated combobox adds spaces.  In your example it would be like value="2 ".  The set code doesn't work in that case.  That is what I am trying to determine.  How can the set see that value in the combo box is 2 just with an extra space?

Comment: ok playing with it more.  your button click event does still work.  When just the set is in the box though it won't set when there is a space next to the 2.  In my code I am trying to set the combo box off of a table row click event so I would think that it would work like your button click but it doesn't.  I just copied the number of spaces in the html into my table "2     " and the click event does set the combo box now.  Very confused.

Comment: You welcome Matt. I edited the (jsFiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/XrDY4/17/] example a bit. Have a look at it again. Should solve your issue